# Reports date axes is null

Tags: reporting

I've rebuild reporting database. After that all reports had been appeared. But reports which are based on Date has empty date axes:[image]

Also I have an error in logs:

> ERROR [Experience Analytics]: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Response.ReportResponseData.ReportRowData..ctor(DataRow row, IReportQueryData queryData, Boolean readKeyIndexColumn)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportingService.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1(DataRow dataRow)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Response.ReportResponseData.DataInflator.NullDataInjector..ctor(IReportQueryData queryData, IEnumerable`1 rows, List`1 dimensionKeys)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Response.ReportResponseData.LiveReportResponseBuilder.WithResults()
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.ReportingService.RunQuery(ReportQuery reportQuery)
>      at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.AnalyticsDataController.Get(ReportQuery reportQuery)

Sitecore 8 update 5
Segments, goals and etc. has been deployed and DeployDate has been overrided to 2001 year before rebuilding.
What can be the reason of these errors?